# Yarn won't use specified registry

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

After running `yarn config set registry https://registry.yarnpkg.com/`, Yarn continuously uses the wrong registry--in this case, https://registry.npmjs.org/.

Here is the output from `yarn config list`:

```
yarn config v1.13.0
info yarn config
{ 'version-tag-prefix': 'v',
  'version-git-tag': true,
  'version-commit-hooks': true,
  'version-git-sign': false,
  'version-git-message': 'v%s',
  'init-version': '1.0.0',
  'init-license': 'MIT',
  'save-prefix': '^',
  'bin-links': true,
  'ignore-scripts': false,
  'ignore-optional': false,
  registry: 'https://registry.yarnpkg.com/',
  'strict-ssl': true,
  'user-agent': 'yarn/1.13.0 npm/? node/v8.11.4 linux x64',
  lastUpdateCheck: 1552699471443 }
info npm config
{ 'strict-ssl': false,
  ca: '',
  registry: 'https://registry.yarnpkg.com/' }
```

As you can see from the output, I also ran `npm config set registry ttps://registry.yarnpkg.com/` to avoid mix ups.  I also checked the .npmrc and .yarnrc files for the any references to the npmjs registry.

***Edit: Also, deleted both the package-lock.json and the yarn.lock files before running `yarn install`. But still the npmjs registry is listed in the new yarn.lock file. It's not using the yarnpkg registry at all.

How can I force Yarn to use a specific registry?

Comment: have you checked the .yarnrc already?

Comment: facing the same issue, has anyone found an answer to this? the answer below didn't help me.

Answer (score 6):

Remove yarn.lock, package-lock.json, all node_modules, .yarnrc and run: `yarn cache clean && yarn install`.

If that doesn't work, remove all again and run: `yarn cache clean && yarn install --registry https://registry.yarnpkg.com/`.

Comment: delete the `yarn.lock` file works

Answer (score 2):

For me, there was a conflict with my user .npmrc. I deleted this file (in C:\Users\{username}) and configured the .npmrc within the root of my project instead.

Comment: It is unintuitive, to say the least, that yarn uses the user-level `.npmrc` over the project-level `.yarnrn`. If "fixed" it by adding a project-level `.npmrc` so that I don't have to mess with my overall npm configuration.